# Android NullPointerException when writing to file

Tags: java, android, json, file-io

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when trying to write to a file in the internal storage and I can't figure out why. I read all the documentation and am using that code to test, but no go.

I am pulling a string with a `HTTP GET request` (it's one single line, but in the JSON format) and am trying to write that string into a `JSON` file in the internal memory.

I know the HTTP GET request is working correctly as I was able to log that into the LogCat, but I am stuck on the part where I want to write it to a JSON file.

**Main Activity**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_checklist);
    mGestureDetector = createGestureDetector(this);

//      JSONReader jsonReader = new JSONReader(this.getApplicationContext());
//      jsonReader.readJson();
//      jsonReader.getData();

    new BackgroundTask().execute("");

    try {
        writeToJSON();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void writeToJSON() throws IOException {
    String filename = "test.json";
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(data.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(1, 2);

        try {
            data = request.GetRequest();
            Log.v("testing", data);
//              request.writeToJSON();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**HTTPRequest**

```
    public String GetRequest() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    URLConnection connection = new URL(listOfChecklistsURL).openConnection();
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
    String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
    for (String param : contentType.replace(" ", "").split(";")) {
        if (param.startsWith("charset=")) {
            charset = param.split("=", 2)[1];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (charset != null) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response, charset));
        try {
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
//                  System.out.println(line);
                data = line;
            }
        }
        finally {
            try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.medusa.checkit/com.medusa.checkit.NewChecklistActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.medusa.checkit.NewChecklistActivity.writeToJSON(NewChecklistActivity.java:52)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.medusa.checkit.NewChecklistActivity.onCreate(NewChecklistActivity.java:42)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-24 16:32:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     ... 11 more
```

**NEW EDITED CODE - Main Activity**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_checklist);
    mGestureDetector = createGestureDetector(this);


    new BackgroundTask();

}

public void writeToJSON() throws IOException {
    String filename = "test.json";
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(data.getBytes());
    fos.close();
}

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(1, 2);

        try {
            data = request.GetRequest();
            Log.v("testing", data);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        try {
            writeToJSON();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: New onPostExecute** works! forgot to `return`

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            Log.v("onPostExecute", "writing to JSON");
            JSONWriter writer = new JSONWriter(context, data);
            writer.writeToJSON();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the crash. We won't be able to figure it out (easily) either if we don't see the error.

Comment: Sorry, was actually editing and adding the stacktrace as you commented.

Comment: I don't understand why it is asking for an empty constructor?

Comment: It seems like you're instantiating an Activity. Don't do that.

Comment: Oops **wrong** stacktrace, just re-edited and posted proper stacktrace lol

Comment: It seems that `fos` is null, which means that probable `openFileOutput()` returns null. Can you post that code as well?

Comment: `FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` this is my only code that creates `fos`. I was under the assumption that `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` creates the file if it not already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an `AsyncTask` is asynchronous, `data` is `null` because the `AsyncTask` hasn't finished before that method is called. Call `writeToJSON()` from `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask` so it won't be called until `data` has a value.

Also, `doInBackground()` returns `null` but according to your task declaration,

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

`onPostExecute()` should expect a `String`. The last `param` should either be `Void` or you should return a `String` from `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Can I change `doInBackground()` to `Void`? As I don't really need to return a String for that, I was just using the template of `AsyncTask`. Is it possible to just use all `Void`s with AsyncTask or does it need to expect something back?

Comment: All `Void` is fine. Just change the declaration so they all have `Void` if none of the methods are expecting anything. Do that then put the method call in `onPostExecute()` as I said in my answer and you should be good

Comment: I think that worked! Not getting any errors. Now just to see how to open the file and see if it wrote correctly. Thanks @codeMagic

Comment: Hmm... does my `protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)` code look correct cause when I try to run the `new BackgroundTask().doInBackground()` it gives me a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which obviously means it's not doing in the background?!

Comment: Looks correct but when you call it you should have `new BackgroundTask().execute();` instead of just `new BackgroundTask();`

Comment: I just changed it to `new BackgroundTask().execute();` and it does the HTTP GET pull correctly, but seems like it never executes `onPostExecute()` as my `Log` never showed up.

Comment: Change `protected void onPostExecute() {` to `protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {` notice the `params`

Comment: I made the change, but still doesn't seem like it's executing. I added the edited `onPostExecute()` above. So confusing...

Comment: Ahhhh got it! Forgot to `return;` in `onPostExecute()`. Thanks again!