# Android - Null pointer on setAdapter function

Tags: android, json, http

I'm working on an app and I'm trying to show a listview filled with information from a MySQL database. I already have a different activity where I send and receive from the database using php, I'm doing something similar. I'm not sure if the error I'm having is something with the adapter class or from the Json Parsing part in the AsyncTask. These are the files:

```
package com.example.xxx.xxx;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    ListView list;
    ArrayList<Places> placeslist;
    PlacesAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_row);
        placeslist = new ArrayList<Places>();
        new JASONTask().execute("http://xxx.xxx.com/getlist.php");

        adapter = new PlacesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_row, placeslist);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public class JASONTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(ListActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line ="";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();

                JSONArray theJson = new JSONArray(finalJson);


                for (int i=0; i<theJson.length(); i++){
                    Places place = new Places();

                    JSONObject jRealObject = theJson.getJSONObject(i);

                    place.setPlaces_id(jRealObject.getString("places_id"));
                    place.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
                    place.setLocation_address(jRealObject.getString("location_address"));

                    placeslist.add(place);
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null){
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result == false){
                //message not parsed
            }

        }
    }

}
```

The Places class is:

```
package com.example.xxx.xxx;

/**
 * Created by manhols on 10/12/2015.
 */
public class Places {

    private String places_id;
    private String name;
    private String location_address;

    public Places(){

    }

    public String getPlaces_id() {
        return places_id;
    }

    public void setPlaces_id(String places_id) {
        this.places_id = places_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation_address() {
        return location_address;
    }

    public void setLocation_address(String location_address) {
        this.location_address = location_address;
    }
}
```

And the PlacesAdapter class is:

```
package com.example.xxx.xxx;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by manhols on 10/12/2015.
 */
public class PlacesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Places>{

    ArrayList<Places> placeslist;
    int Resource;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater vi;

    public PlacesAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Places> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        Resource = resource;
        placeslist = objects;

        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            convertView = vi.inflate(Resource,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textView5 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }

        holder.textView.setText(placeslist.get(position).getName());
        holder.textView2.setText(placeslist.get(position).getPlaces_id());
        holder.textView5.setText(placeslist.get(position).getLocation_address());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        public TextView textView2;
        public TextView textView5;
    }
}
```

I will highly appreciate any help solving this issue.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace generated when you encountered the exception.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is asynchronous as the name suggests. This means that it most likely isn't completed before the rest of the code is executed. You need to call a function in `onPostExecute()` to handle the adapter or put it directly in that method

Comment: But, yes, post your stacktrace. I have a feeling that `setContentView(R.layout.single_row);` is inflating the layout for your rows in your `ListView`. It should be inflating the layout which actually contains your `ListView` so it is `null` when you try initializing it `list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);`

Comment: Thank you @codeMagic you were right! I had the issue with the wrong layout. I fixed it and now it's not giving me the setadapter error. However I have a new problem. 
It seems like the Json object is coming out empty. I will update the thread with the issue

Comment: No, create a new post for that if you can't figure it out. But your new problem is most likely due to [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138499/android-null-pointer-on-setadapter-function?noredirect=1#comment54088255_33138499) see [this answer about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768086/android-nullpointerexception-when-writing-to-file/20768127#20768127)

Comment: Please don't change your post to a completely different problem. Once you've given it a try, researched, and still stuck, post a new question with the relevant code and error messages, etc...

Comment: @codeMagic Ok, I will try and debug my app and do more research before having to enter a new post. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: No problem. But that link to an answer of mine should help out. You just need to set the adapter in `onPostExecute()` so the list has time to populate

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted some errors in your adapter. Please inflate row as  `convertView = vi.inflate(Resource,parent,false);` and also in parsing the data , return true only in try block. From your code i can see that even if you have an exception, you will be returning true which is wrong.

Comment: Hello Sri, thanks for your help. My problem was in the setContentView as @codeMagic mentioned before. I already solved this thanks to him. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, I haven't seen that line. Thank you for mentioning about. But use return statement as I said , it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the setContentView as @codeMagic mentioned before. I already solved this thanks to him